# Does not start MongoDB 4

Tags: mongodb

I just started learning MongoDB. When I run for the first time, I get an error.
MongoDB 4 version
Windows 10 x64

MongoDB shell version v4.0.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-08-13T00:15:54.149+0300 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

Comment: That's the shell, You also have to start `mongod`, the server.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you created the /data/db at the root. otherwise, do the simple steps.

**For Mac or Linux user**

1 - first open the terminal as root.

```
sudo bash
```

2 - make db folder

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

3 - give the chmod 777 to the directory.

```
chmod 777 /data
chmod 777 /data/db
```

4 - confirm the /data/db is 777

```
ls -ld /data/db
```

5 - exit the root shell

6 - run the mongod cmd at mongodb_path/bin directory.

```
mongod
```

make sure it is listing port. By default, it listens to the 27017 port.

7- open the new terminal window and run the mongo cmd at mongodb_path/bin directory.

```
mongo
```

**For window user**

1- create the /data/db at like C:\data\db

2- open the terminal at mongodb_path/bin

```
mongod
```

make sure it is listing port. By default, it listens to the 27017 port.

3- open the new terminal window at mongodb_path/bin

```
mongo
```

Comment: Thanks. I searched lot of method to resolve my problem.. my problem is (MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-12-19T07:35:33.904+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed)

Answer (score 0):

Please check weather bellow steps did u follow:

1) Install MongoDB

2) create path to store data (eg: C:\data\db)

3) Go to bin location from cmd

```
 cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.XXX\bin
```

4) Then enter

```
mongod
```

5) Then open another cmd and enter

```
 mongo
```

Comment: Thank you. Working!

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it may happen if you try to reach a mongodb server from another ip and it stops you because of mongodb configurations.

At the location you have installed mongodb (in my computer it is C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin) you will see the config file: mongod.cfg. When you open the file for editing you will find some parameters under net part. As default, it is like the following:

## network interfaces

net:

port: 27017

bindIp: 127.0.0.1

But if you want to connect to mongodb from another machine you have to change it as following:

## network interfaces

net:

port: 27017

bindIp: 0.0.0.0

When you change it as 0.0.0.0, it means it accepts connections from all ip.